# My pipenv didn't work correctly

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyenv, pipenv

I have a vagant box ubuntu/xenial64-20180105 and there is python2.7.12 python3.5.2 defaultly, when I init(vagrant ssh),I use pyenv to install python3.6.4 and set python3.6.4 to my default env

```
pyenv install 3.6.4
pyenv global 3.6.4
```

I want use pipenv to manager to devel env so 
    pip install --user pipenv

```
cd mydevel

pipenv --three
```

but some error happend lik this:
[image]

the error message said pipenv can't find python interapter but when i run 
    python
it works?
I think i need some help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one with this problem. It is in their FAQ: https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/#pipenv-does-not-respect-pyenvs-global-and-local-python-versions

**In short:** 
`Pipenv` by default will not look at the `pyenv` python version. It'll use the version defined in the `PIPENV_DEFAULT_PYTHON_VERSION` env var.

To make `Pipenv` respect the version set by `pyenv`, there are 3 way of doing that. You can either:

- Update your `Pipfile` with the correct version:
     
  `[requires]
  python_version = "3.6.4"`
- Manually specify the exact python with the `--python` option: `pipenv --python 3.6.4`
- Set `pipenv` to **always** use the `pyenv` python version, regardless of what's in the `Pipfile`. To do that, set the `PIPENV_PYTHON` enviroment var to `$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python`

Comment: to add on to the answer: pipenv --python $(pyenv which python)